# Clearing a previous Label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program that searches a database file for current video game prices. I got this working in the console but I am trying to transition it into a GUI for better looks and decided to try tkinter. Below is the function I'm having a problem with:

```
def getPrice():

    console = variable.get()
    game = gameSearch.get()

    with open('price-guide.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[1] == console and game.lower() in row[2].lower():
                price = f"""Game Title: {row[2].upper()}
Loose: {row[3]}
CIB: {row[4]}
New: {row[5]}
"""
                priceLabel = Label(root, text=price)
                priceLabel.pack()
    csv_file.close()
```

Currently the program works great, I can select a console (Playstation 2), search for a game (God of War), and it will return a series of labels with pricing information "priceLabel". But if I do a new search, it will simply add to the bottom of the previous search results. I tried searching for other solutions but being that I only started learning tkinter today I'm not sure I've stumbled past the solution without even knowing it.

Even being able to 'refresh' the program without having to close and run it again would work for my needs.

Comment: You would need to save references to all of your Labels (in a list, perhaps), so that you can later call `.destroy()` on each one to get rid of it.  Another approach would be to add the Labels to a Frame, rather than directly to the root window; you could then call `.destroy()` on the Frame to get rid of all the Labels at once (and then create a new Frame for the next batch of Labels).

Comment: You can change the options of any existing widget by calling its [`config()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method. In order do do this, you will need to save them all in a container like a list or dictionary so you can refer to them again as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're packing new Label widgets at the bottom. Each time you create a new `Label` instance and call `pack()`, you will pack a new widget into the GUI.

One solution would be to use a list of labels and then destroy each one, then repopulate the results:

````
    console = variable.get()
    game = gameSearch.get()

    priceLabels = []
    with open('price-guide.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        # clear the labels
        for priceLabel in priceLabels:
            priceLabel.destroy()

        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[1] == console and game.lower() in row[2].lower():
                price = f"""Game Title: {row[2].upper()}
Loose: {row[3]}
CIB: {row[4]}
New: {row[5]}
"""
                priceLabel = Label(root, text=price)
                # add to list to clear in the future
                priceLabels.append(priceLabel)
                priceLabel.pack()
    csv_file.close()```
````